# Powershell: Fancy new cmdlet to install CRLs too?

Tags: powershell, certificate, ad-certificate-services, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-8.1

So Win8.1 and 2012 R2 includes a neat new cmdlet to install certs:

```
Import-Certificate [-FilePath] <String> [-CertStoreLocation <String> ] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Unfortunately I found it does not install CRLs- booo. This is weird especially because the equivalent certutil.exe command *can* do both indiscriminately:

```
certutil -addstore -f Root <whatev.crt | whatev.crl>
```

I was not able to find an "Import-CertificateRevocationList" either. Seems like an oversight which is why I want to confirm there actually is no simple, native cmdlet for this (not multi-line scripts or 3rd party cmdlets like Quest).

Is there really no cmdlet for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. Keep using certutil.exe.

Comment: Aw shucks, I guess using certutil.exe with PS is easy enough for now.